# Get rows from A table with multiple records where last record has a value of X

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables in mariadb

Table 1
id,did,status

Table 2 id,did,status

Table 1 can contain multiple records with the same did

So first step is I am trying to consolidate this into 1 row with the status being the highest entered id

For example if we have the following 3 rows

0, 9923323344, -1

1, 9923323344, -1

2, 9923323344, 1

Then the row I would get back is

0, 9923323344, 1

My attempt at this is

```mysql
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE carrier='2' ORDER BY id DESC) GROUP BY did
```

Which gives me back wrong results for a specific example I got back

0,2078009797, -1

When I was expecting

0,2078009797, 1

The second part of this is once I have a correct list I would then like to get all of the rows out of this list that have a status of -1

```mysql
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE carrier='2' ORDER BY id DESC) GROUP BY did) AND status='-1'
```

This also returns incorrect results as I get the following back for a specific example

0,2078009797, -1

1,2078009797, -1

2,2078009797, -1

When I was expecting

0,2078009797, 1

And then finally the last part of this is to check the list from the last query against Table2 and see if there is any rows with a status!='-1' AND did=Table1.did